# How to save a workbook using a value from a referenced cell as the file name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save a workbook with the value from a cell as the file name.

This code will save it as a specific file name,

```
ActiveSheet.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Desktop\temp1"
```

I need to use a unique file name based on what is in the file.

I tried the following, but receive

> runtime '1004' error

stating that the file could not be accessed.

```vb
Sub Save_Workbook()
' Saves workbook as filename

Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\Desktop\"
FileName = Range("K5").Value & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

End Sub
```

Comment: Does `FileName` contain any invalid characters for a filename?

Comment: @BigBen Yes. I had a ":" in part of it. Changing it to a "." fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the formatting of the contents of the target cell. Part of the string in the cell was 12:01. Once this was changed to 12.01, the issue was resolved.